# Is it possible to be attacked with XSS on style tag which having inline styling?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>XSS test</title>
        <style>
        div {
            background-color:red;
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Would it be possible to inject `JavaScript` code using inside style tag? I have heard that it's possible to trigger `XSS` attacks through `CSS`.

Comment: This example is static, so there is no possibility to attack it with XSS.

Comment: Example of attacks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546591/xss-attacks-and-style-attributes?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Yes, JavaScript can be executed even through CSS thanks to URL support in the latter. In general, you can execute JavaScript through any mechanism that allows you to specify URLs because of the `javascript:` and `data:` pseudo-URLs. As result there are numerous cross-site scripting vectors that work through CSS. For example:

```
<style>p[foo=bar{}*{-o-link:'javascript:alert(1)'}{}*{-o-link-source:current}*{background:red}]{background:green};</style>
```

More of them can be found on Mario Heiderich site http://heideri.ch/jso/#css