# Javascript inline style CSP violation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy, gsap

I'm currently implementing CSP in our Rails application, we use a library called SplitText VERSION: 0.6.1 from https://greensock.com/SplitText/ and I'm having some issues.

[image]

The code from this library is in a `.js` file and it's imported and used by other components.

Is there a way of using a nonce for local imported libraries similar to what is applied to script tags when loading remote sources?

Or is it possible to ignore CSP violations coming from a specific file?
I don't want to use `unsafe-inline`

Comment: Please post text and code instead of pictures. Did you google the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SplitText vendor informed us that they use this pattern for performance reasons and have no intention of modifying this behaviour.
https://greensock.com/forums/topic/34053-splittext-inline-style-content-security-policy-violation

Here's a good explanation of why this javascript violates the `inline-style` rule ["inline-style"-Error with Content Security Policy and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401952/inline-style-error-with-content-security-policy-and-javascript/42402277#42402277) and how it could be prevented.

The way we can work around this issue is to use the `unsafe-hashes` header with the respective sha256 hash.